# ComboBox selected item won't update name unless I select a different item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ComboBox with a list of names of objects. When I perform my rename command, the selected item's name changes in the list of items but will not show the updated name at the top unless I click to a different object then back. Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: "Test System 1" has been renamed to "test" but is not being updated in the selection unless I click out and back.]

Here is my ComboBox xaml:

```
<ComboBox Name="CSCB" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="8"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Systems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoord, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Text="Select a Coordinate System"
                      />
```

Let me know if I should include more code. Thank you :)

Comment: Pls show us your rename command!

Comment: @Elhamer I forgot that I had removed the command and simply used a TwoWay binding for Rename with a text box that pops up: <TextBox Name="NewNameTB" Text="{Binding SelectedCoord.Name, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"

Comment: In my case if displayed 'Name' property properly uses implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged (so it calls OnPropertyChanged) it is refreshed in combobox (both on list and selected one) right away!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to either re-implement a custom `combobox` that do that, or you could simply refresh the `combobox` items manually on the `TextChanged` event like so:

```
  private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CSCB.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

Assuming your xaml looks something like that:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="CSCB" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="8" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Systems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCoord, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Text="Select a Coordinate System"
    />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedCoord.Name,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"></TextBox>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: There might be also another way to do that by editing a copy of the `combobox` `controltemplate`